# Position content in browser to match repeated background

Tags: html, css, flash, browser, alignment

I have a background that repeats and positions like this:

```
body
{
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

This works fine. Now I want to center the content of the page. If I have a image that is 1000x560px I would like it to be aligned to match the background that is now centered in the browser.

Best approach?

[image]

Comment: Wrap your content in one container. Give height,width to your content.use margin:auto to centered in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for you content div you can use `position:absolute` . write like this:

```
.content{
 width:1000px;
 height:560px;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-230px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-500px
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I don´t have a div. If it must be placed in the body?

Comment: then target the <img> tag directly, giving it the class `content`. The CSS here does not have to be applied to a div.

Answer (score 0):

If you now have your centered background image applied to the body tag, you could declare a container to then sit in the center of your page like so:

```
#container {
width: 1000px;
height: 560px;
margin: 20% 0 auto;
}
```

This could create a container sitting directly over your background and will re-size depending on the size of your window. The only thing i cant work out for you is the top margin percentage, you might have to play around with this to get it correct. In this case i have declared it as 20%, also note i have only tested this in FF

Let me know how that works out and if ive understood you correctly.

Cheers